# imp.get_suffixes() is deprecated,how to repair it?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, deprecated, python-importlib

I have encountered :

```
pywintypes.py:39: DeprecationWarning: imp.get_suffixes() is deprecated; 
use the constants defined on importlib.machinery instead
```

but i don't know how to repair it ?
could any one explain for me in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message explains you should use the `_SUFFIXES` constants that are part of [`importlib.machinery`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.machinery). These were introduced in Python 3.3. The deprecation message means you should now use those constants instead of calling `imp.get_suffixes()`.

If you can't upgrade to Python 3.3 yet then that's fine (things currently still work) but it's something to be aware of when upgrading in the future.

Comment: what's the function of `imp.get_suffixes()`,isn't it just a constant like `_suffixes`? do you know ?

Comment: there is a function named `all_suffixes()` in the `importlib.machinery` ,should i use it to replace the `imp.get_suffixes()`?

Comment: i replaced it ,and it work fine ,but there is another depreciation named `the markdown filter has been depreciated`,thank you

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated does not mean that it is broken and need repairing. It simply means that you should avoid using this function because it will soon be gotten rid of and possibly superseded by something else. In this case it is saying to use the constants in importlib.machinery. Your code should still work if you ignore the warning, it just won't be future-proofed, i.e an update may break your code.

Comment: i know ,but i am caring future-proofed,and i hate warnings.